# Css and Media Queries

Tags: html, css

I have the following css where I want to scale out from a page on smaller resolution screens

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1331px) {
    .homePageStyle {
        transform-origin: 70px 0px;
        transform: scale(0.93, 0.93); 
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in chrome, but in IE it leaves a good bit of padding on the right hand side of the page and shows a scrollbar

Is there anything I can add to this to stop a scroll bar appearing and have no padding on the right in IE

Comment: which version of IE you are using?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: we are using IE 11

Comment: can you post a code snippet for your code. It will help me to figure out the problem in better way. Try js fiddle, codepen or SO in-buiilt feature. Also do add a image of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend just setting the `overflow-y: hidden;`. The scrollbar automatically adds padding, and overflow-y just gets rid of it as a whole. Mind you, it shouldn't cut anything off if you have your screen size and all configured correctly with the media property.


Your code:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1331px) {
    .homePageStyle {
        transform-origin: 70px 0px;
        transform: scale(0.93, 0.93); 
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
}
```

Difference between overflow-y and overflow-x and overflow in general is overflow-y only changes affects on the screen vertically whereas overflow affects the screen overflow as a whole, and overflow-x obviously affects the horizontal part. I mean, if you know your graphs, it's basically (x,y), but you can't scroll over to see the remainders of that figure if it's out of the default view.

Answer (score 1):

IE had lots of problems. So there are two things you could do.First target IE specific browser and second use browser vendor prefixes.

For IE 10+ you can use following code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1331px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
 /* Affects IE10+ only*/
  .homePageStyle {
       -ms-transform-origin: 70px 0px;
       -ms-transform: scale(0.93, 0.93); 
       padding-right:0; /*see if it do the magic else ignore */
       overflow:hidden;
   }

 }
```

For IE 9 and lower you can use conditional comment

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-9andbelowonly.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You can also use some hack

For IE 6,7 and 8

```
@media \0screen\,screen\9 {
    selector{ /*css rules*/ }
}
```

For IE 8

```
@media \0screen{
    selector{ /*css rules*/ }
}
```

For IE 8

```
@media screen\0{
    selector{ /*css rules*/ }
}
```

Note: They are hacks. Hence they may or may not work.

Reference:

[Moving IE specific CSS into media blocks](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/)

[How To Create an IE-Only Stylesheet](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: just tried the overflow: hidden but unfortunately it has the same issue and it didnt resolve it

Comment: @Damien does this addresses your first problem regarding padding.

Comment: It doesn't sorry, I tried what you mentioned and it did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

IE has historically had problems with the `transform` property. I do not know what version you are using but IE11 supports these properties.

If you are using earlier versions give `-ms-transform` a try:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1331px) {
.homePageStyle {
    -ms-transform-origin: 70px 0px;
    -ms-transform: scale(0.93, 0.93);
    transform-origin: 70px 0px;
    transform: scale(0.93, 0.93); 
}
}
```

As a note, you can hide overflowing content with CSS if it is suitable (it may very well not be in your scenario, but again, I would need more info before giving anything conclusive):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1331px) {
.homePageStyle {
    transform-origin: 70px 0px;
    transform: scale(0.93, 0.93); 
    overflow: hidden;
}
}
```

If you have something I can look at I'd be happy to provide further support.

The following post might also be of assistance, in at least explaining why such problems occur: [IE showing horizontal scrollbar after dom element transformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990347/ie-showing-horizontal-scrollbar-after-dom-element-transformed)

Comment: We are using IE 11. Just tried these options but with no joy unfortunately. Also this is on an internal company intranet site to there is nothing I can share

Comment: You can share a minimal example that reproduces the problem, there is no need to post the whole page